# If $g(x) = \sup_{z \in [x, b]} f(z)$ is a concave function then $f(x)$ is also concave

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Assume $f(x)$ is defined and bounded on $[a, b]$ and $g(x) = \sup_{z \in [x, b]} f(z)$. Then if  $g(x)$ is a strictly concave on $[a, b]$ function then $f(x)$ is also a strictly concave on $[a, b]$ function.

As I know $\forall \ x_1, x_2 \in [a, b], \forall \ t \in [0, 1] \to \ g(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) > tg(x_1) + (1-t)g(x_2)$ and I need to prove that $\forall \ x_1, x_2 \in [a, b], \forall \ t \in [0, 1] \to \ f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) > tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2)$

I've managed to conclude that $tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2) \leq tg(x_1) + (1-t)g(x_2) < g(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \ge f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)$

Could you please give me any hints what to do next?
Thanks in advance!

$\mathbf{Update}$ The foregoing statement is false and the counter example is $f(x)=(1−x^2) \mathbb{1}_Q(x)$ not a strictly concave function despite of the strictly concave $g(x) = (1-x^2)$

Comment: Should $f$ be continuous? If not, then the statement is false. Just define $f(x)= (1-x^2) 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ on $[0,1]$. Then $g(x) = (1-x^2)$ is strictly concave, but $f$ not!

Comment: @p4sch $f(x)$ is said to be "defined and bounded on $[a, b]$" I think it means that it's defined at each point of $[a, b]$, I will edit the question. Thank you a lot.

Comment: $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$. Here $1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the indicator function of $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. zero if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and one if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @p4sch yes, I'm sorry, I've understood

Comment: @p4sch, since this is in the context of real analysis and by looking at the statement, I guess $f$ is implicitly assumed to at least be continuous, perhaps also differentiable. Your proposed example fails there. But otherwise, what the statement explicitly reads is false and your counterexample works great!

Comment: @PrasunBiswas It would be nice, if you were right, but in my textbook this task looks like I've written it, and nothing said about the continuity of $f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not continious, then the statement is false. (See my counterexample in the comments.) On the contrary, assuming that $f$ is continious, the statement is true.

Proof: Define $M:= \sup_{h \in [a,b]} f(x)$. By continuity at least one point exists $x \in [a,b]$ with $f(x) =M$. If another $y \in [a,b]$, say $x < y$, exists with $f(x) = f(y)=M$, then $$M= t f(x) +(1-t) = t g(x) +(1-t) g(y) < g(tx+(1-t)y) =f(v)$$
for some $v \in [tx+(1-t)y,b]$. A contradiction, because $M$ is the supremum! So there is only one global maximum.

We have already $x=a$. If the smallest $x \in [a,b]$ with $f(x) = M$ is bigger than $a$, we get $f(y) < f(x)$ for all $y \in [a,x)$, since there is only one global maximum. Thus $g(y) = M$ for every $y \leq x$. That's not a  strictly concave function!

We can use the first agument on $[h,b]$ instead of $[a,b]$, since $f$ restricted to $[h,b]$ satisfies the initial condtions, in order to show that already $f(h) = g(h)$.

Note that $g$ is already strictly montone decreasing. For $v < w$ exists $t \in (0,1)$ with $v= ta +(1-t)w$, and by strictly concavity we have 
$$g(w) < t g(a) + (1-t) g(w) \leq g) < g(v).$$